Find all values of parameters a, b such that the limit of the function is finite
From my uni's textbook:
Find all values of parameters $a$ and $b$ such that the following limit is a finite number:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)-\arcsin (bx)-3x}{x^{3}}$$
The fact that $x$ is approaching $0$ is sort of pressuring me to use the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x}= 1 $ (*)
What I've tried (and I am not sure if it's mathematically correct approach) is:
$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (ax)-\arcsin (bx)-3x}{x^{3}}\ = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(ax).a}{a.x^{3}} - \frac{arcsin(bx).b}{b.x^{3}}-\frac{3}{x^{2}}$
Using this (*) fact, I get rid of $sin(ax)$ and $arcsin(bx)$ and :
$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(ax).a}{a.x^{3}} - \frac{arcsin(bx).b}{b.x^{3}}-\frac{3}{x^{2}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a-b-3}{x^{2}}$
and this will converge only if $a-b-3=0$ so my answer to this problem would be that :
$a=b+3$ where both $a,b$ are real numbers.
I am not entirely sure whether I can split the fraction inside the limit (like I did) and then put it back together... I did consider using l'hospital but I got stuck once I derived the function because I think that the process of derivation led to the loss of some solutions.
Any ideas? Opinions? I would appreciate it.

use l'Hopital and it will collapse; add your steps in doing the derivatives.

The simplest is based on Taylor series

No, you can not do that. Here is an example: $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}$$
If using your method,  the value will be $0$. However, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{3x^2}=\frac{1}{6}$
To solve this problem, using L'Hopital 's Rule is convenient.
$$\begin{align} \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin (ax)-\arcsin (bx)-3x}{x^3}&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a\cos(ax)-\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-3}{3x^2}\\
&= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a\cos(ax)-b-3}{3x^2}\\ &=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{-a^2\sin(ax)}{6x}=\frac{-a^3}{6}\end{align}$$
For the penultimate equality, we need $a-b-3=0$.

In general, substituting $x = 0$ into or taking the limit of parts of expressions without evaluating the other parts of the expression at the same point will lead to problems.
My approach would be to perform a series expansion about $x = 0$:
$$\sin ax = ax - \frac{(ax)^3}{3!} + O(x^5),$$
and
$$\arcsin bx = bx + \frac{(bx)^3}{3!} + O(x^5).$$
Hence
$$\frac{\sin ax - \arcsin bx - 3x}{x^3} = (a-b-3)x^{-2} - \frac{a^3+b^3}{6} + O(x^2),$$
so if the limit as $x \to 0$ exists, we require the coefficient of $x^{-2}$ to be zero; i.e., $a-b = 3$.  We also get as a bonus that in such a case, the limit equals $$-\frac{(b+3)^3+b^3}{6} = -\frac{(2b+3)(b^2+3b+9)}{6}.$$

We have
$${\sin (ax)-\arcsin(bx)-3x\over x^3}\\ =a^3\,{\sin(ax)-ax\over (ax)^3}-b^3\,{\arcsin (bx)-bx\over (bx)^3}+{a-b-3\over x^2}$$ The first two fractions have limits at $0.$ So our expression has a limit at $0$ iff the last fraction has a limit, which occurs only when $a-b-3=0.$
Remark The second limit can be reduced to the first one by substition $y=\arcsin(bx).$ Then
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\arcsin (bx)-bx\over (bx)^3}=\lim_{y\to 0}{y-\sin y\over y^3}\,{y^3\over \sin^3y }$$
